# Kanna( XML/HTML parser) swift3 don't install

Tags: swift3

I can't install Kanna in Swift 3.0. I have the following in my PodFile:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Kanna', '~> 2.0.0'
```

It am getting the following error:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `Kanna (~> 2.0.0)` required by `Podfile`
> - `Kanna (~> 2.0.0)` required by `Podfile`
> - `Kanna (~> 2.0.0)` required by `Podfile`
>
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency:
>   `Kanna (~> 2.0.0)`.
>
> You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with
>   `pod repo update`.  * mistyped the name or version.  * not added the
>   source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
>
> Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod
>   install` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaPods *(0.39 or later)* is required ⚠️

You missed a `'` in your `PodFile`:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Kanna', '~> 2.0.0'
```

You can try the following if it's still not working by using commits:

```
pod 'Kanna', :git => 'https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna.git', :commit => '6ae52df72adf42e20147c98c77732d51e0e9294b'
```

Comment: Try by using a commit ID